# Unable to Connecting to Amazon instance EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm Using AWS - Amazon Web Services and running commands from MAC Terminal

http://ec2-52-xx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

But I am getting this error :

Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host

I'm unable to access the site anymore because of this error
there is a security group applied to this instance
and port 22 for ssh is listed under this security group

Comment: I think you're saying that you cannot access the host over HTTP. Can you SSH to it and find out if a web server is actually running? Or use the AWS console to stop/start it to see if a reboot fixes it?

Comment: I tried to shh to it and is sys: ssh: Could not resolve hostname i: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: That's an indication that DNS resolution has failed. Check the host name (whatever ec2-52-xx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com is in reality). Are you sure that your EC2 instance is actually running *and* actually has that assigned public DNS name?

Answer (score 3):

[Check the security group for this instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) and try telnet IP <*allow inbound port*> . If the telnet is happening on any of these ports this means connectivity is there.

Now comes ssh, by default ssh is on port 22, which as per you already allowed in security group. So you need to check if anyone has changed the sshd_config file and changed the ports?

Comment: @Nadosh were you able to telnet to port 22 earlier or this is a new incident?

Answer (score 1):

> port 22 for ssh is listed under this security group

This does not imply anything. Which are the IP addresses allowed to access? Also, check your dns name isn't changed as suggested by jarmod.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of DNS changes thanks, and all IP address can access it for all rules, ssh,http, https 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: It set to anywhere + 0.0.0.0/0  for all rules

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, an inbound firewall protects the network against incoming traffic from the internet or other network segments, namely disallowed connections, malware and denial-of-service attacks. An outbound firewall protects against outgoing traffic originating inside an enterprise network.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the host is actually still named ec2-52-xx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com? Each time you stop and restart an Amazon EC2 instance, the public DNS name will change. Double check it in the AWS console.

Comment: yeah I know that , and for each time I copy the public DNS again and check it in the browser .. thanks

Comment: You're going to have to start debugging, I think. Does the AWS console show the instance is healthy? Does the instance's system log show anything unusual? Assuming inbound ICMP is open, can you ping the host? Does a stop/start correct the issue? For other troubleshooting options see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html and https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connectivity-linux/

Comment: How to Start Debugging ?

Comment: Did you work through the list of debugging options that I mentioned in my previous post? What were the results?

Answer (score 0):

Check both incoming and outgoing rules for port 22, also try with the allocated IP4

Answer (score 0):

```
To connect using the SSH, ssh should be installed correctly on your machine

just type **"SSH"** if something like this comes up that means your machine has ssh


*usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]*

Mostly **Linux and macOS X** have already installed if not then go to the
[here][1]  


For **Windows Server** 2019 and Windows 10 [Openssh in Windows][2]


The first check is there any problem with your ssh is allowed from the security group of that particular instance 


like is it allowing to connect from ssh or not

once that is confirmed you have to enter the correct syntax to connect the AWS instance 

Using Public DNS that is available under the running instance

**ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-public-dns-name**

Using ipv6 similarly, ipv4 can be done

**ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-IPv6-address**

in place of **my-instance-user-name** you can through documentation provided by AWs[1]


  [1]: http://www.openssh.com
  [2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview
```